# Django filter intermediary table & social media

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

So i'm practicing django with a social media website(just for practice).  I'm trying to do a filter in my view to get all of the "Beats" from users i'm friends with.  Im using an intermediary table for "relationships".  I'm currently getting my Beat Stream by using:

```
my_stream = Beat.objects.filter(artist=user)
```

But i'm trying to get only the beats of the people i'm "related_to" in the relationships model.

MODELS:

```
class Beat(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField( default=datetime.now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    beat_cover = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True);
    admin_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.admin_name)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    admin_name = models.CharField(default="beat",max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.admin_name)

class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="relationships")
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="related_to")

    class Meta:
        index_together = ['from_user','to_user']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
related_users = Relationship.objects.filter(from_user=user) \
                                    .values_list('to_user', flat=True).distinct()
my_stream = Beat.objects.filter(artist__in=related_users)
```